# Implementing if/else logic in SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, reporting-services

Im in the process of creating an SSRS report (which Im fairly new at), and my query is written in t-sql using SQL Server 2008.

The query is an IF EXISTS/ELSE statement that basically reads -

```
--Declare @variable varchar(10) = 'value'
IF EXISTS (SELECT col1 
           FROM t1 
           WHERE t1.col1 = @variable
          )
SELECT col1 
FROM t1 
WHERE t1.col1 = @variable

ELSE

SELECT col1, col2
FROM t2
WHERE t2.col1 = @variable
```

This runs fine in Mgmt studio, but when I try to make a tablix in SSRS, columns from t2 are left out of the dataset - which makes sense, because the entire query has to run to determine which result set is returned, and that can't happen in ssrs until the end user assigns a value to @variable, so the dataset [from the first result set] is shown by default.

That being said, how can I implement this type of logic in a report?

Comment: You'll need to make the data returned from either query match - as if you were UNIONing them. It looks like you just need to add a **col2** to the **T1** table - `SELECT col1, '' AS col2`.

Comment: This is where it gets complicated. The data from t2 represents a calculation performed on replicated data from t1 with additional information shown based on the calculation output (initiated by the end user via variable), so I can't exactly use a union.

Comment: You don;t need to use a UNION. @HannoverFist was saying "as-if doing a UNION". You just need to make sure that the query returns the same number of columns with the same datatypes no matter which select statement is actually run. so just add col2 to your first query as and empty string or zero or whatever to match the column type of col2 in t2

Comment: My mistake, I misread. I understand what you're saying now. I will try that.

Comment: @HannoverFist I created a temp column with the same datatype and it works great. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Alan Schofield thank you again for correcting me

Comment: No problem, always happy to help...

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to add a parameter to your report. In the left bar at the top left is the parameter folder. You can right click that an add a parameter.

Your parameter is passed into your query just like @variable. Replace @variable with @yourparametername. When you execute the query in the query designer, a dialog will pop up and allow you to enter a parameter so the query can execute. This will allow SSRS to read the columns and show them in the dataset.

Comment: On second look, you're going to want to make the first select return a value for col2 because the dataset is going to expect consistent column returns.

Comment: Hannover Fist beat me to it!